# Why does not work scrolling in naniScroller to element?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, nanoscroller

I use Jquery NanoScroller on page:

```
$timeout(function () {

    $('.dialog-window .nano').nanoScroller({preventPageScrolling: true, scrollTo: $('#lastMesasage')});
    }, 500);
```

But this code does not scroll block `.dialog-window .nano` to `#lastMesasage`. Also does not show scrolling line.

If remnove `scrollTo: $('#lastMesasage')}` from options, the scroll line appears.

Comment: Any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: There are not errors

Answer (score 0):

`#lastMesasage`, I would assume, is a typo (should be `#lastMessage`?)

If you've written the `id` on the element without a typo, there'll be no match - so it won't have an element to scroll to.

Note: This *is* an assumption, so I'll accept downvotes if I was wrong as I don't  like to make a habit of answering based on assumptions.

Comment: No, here is `lastMessage` everywhere, I have done mistake when posted question

Comment: May be block `<div id="lastMessage"></div>` whould be in any block, that is scrolled?

Comment: I don't understand your second comment sorry.